# Uniswap price oracle

Tags: uniswap, exchanges

How can I access the Uniswap exchange rate for a specific pool? For example purposes lets assume I'm trying to find ETH to AAVE.

Comment: You need this information on smart contract level or outside the blockchain?

Comment: Smart contract level

Comment: See [the question regarding price oracles](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/114987/620).

Answer (score 1):

The following example is made to work on the mainnet, if you wish to use it on one of the testnets you must replace the following contract addresses:

1. `0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D` is the contract address of Uniswap Router V2
2. `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2` is the contract address of WETH

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestContract {
    UniswapRouter UR = UniswapRouter(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
    
    function getPairETHRate(uint256 _eth_amount, address _token_contract) public view returns(uint) {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
        path[1] = _token_contract;
        
        uint firstReturnedParam;
        uint secondReturnedParam;
        (firstReturnedParam, secondReturnedParam) = UR.getAmountsOut(_eth_amount, path);
        
        return secondReturnedParam;
    }
}
 
interface UniswapRouter {
    function getAmountsOut(uint, address[] memory) external view returns (uint[] memory);
}
```

Ok so in my example you have the method called `getPairETHRate` which is accepting ETH amount in wei for first parameter and the second parameter is the token contract address ( in your case that would be AAVE contract address ). So when you pass 100000000000000000 wei ( 0.1 ETH ) as first parameter the method will return how much tokens you can get right now from the uniswap pair by swapping 0.1 ETH. Feel free to test it.

If for example the token is being listed on more pairs for example USDT, you can paste the USDT contract address on `path[0]` and then you will get the /USDT exchange rate.